# Complex mxArray cumulative elements sum

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I'm trying to have the sum of a complex mxArray elements (which has to be done for the real and imaginary part separately I believe) .. here's my code

```
 #include <boost/math/special_functions/bessel.hpp>
 #include <boost/math/special_functions/legendre.hpp>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 #include <complex>
 #include "mex.h"
 #include "math.h"
 #include "matrix.h"

 using namespace std;


void mexFunction (int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mxArray *wave_num,*rho,*phi, *r,*data3,*img_mat,*out;
    int k;
    double *vr,*vi,*j_sphere_bessel, *n_sphere_bessel, *mul_j_p,*mat_1,*mat_2,*R_ptr,*I_ptr;
    double rho1,phi1,r1,R,I;
    double *rptr, *iptr;



    wave_num = prhs[0];
    k = (int)(mxGetScalar(wave_num)); 

    vr = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    vi = mxGetPi(prhs[1]);

    r = prhs[2];
    r1 = (double)(mxGetScalar(r));

    rho = prhs[3];
    rho1 = (double)(mxGetScalar(rho));

    phi = prhs[4];
    phi1 = (double)(mxGetScalar(phi));


    j_sphere_bessel     = (double *) mxMalloc(1*5 * sizeof(double));
    n_sphere_bessel     = (double *) mxMalloc(1*5 * sizeof(double));

    mul_j_p =  (double *) mxMalloc(1*5 * sizeof(double)); 
    mat_1   =  (double *) mxMalloc(1*5 * sizeof(double));
    mat_2   =  (double *) mxMalloc(1*5 * sizeof(double));


    rptr = mxGetPr(img_mat); // ADDED
    iptr = mxGetPi(img_mat); // ADDED

    img_mat = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 1, mxCOMPLEX);

    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1, 5, mxREAL);   

    for (int o=0;o<5;o++)
    {       
        j_sphere_bessel[o]  =     boost::math::sph_bessel(o, k*rho1);

        n_sphere_bessel[o]  =    -boost::math::sph_neumann(o, k*rho1);

        mul_j_p [o]  = ((2*o)+1)*(boost::math::sph_bessel(o, k*r1))*(boost::math::legendre_p(o, cos(phi1*3.14159265/180))); 

        mat_1 [o]  = mul_j_p[o]*j_sphere_bessel[o];
        mat_2 [o]  = mul_j_p[o]*n_sphere_bessel[o];
        R = R + mat_1[o];
        I = I + mat_2[o]; 

      rptr[o] = R; // ADDED
      iptr[o] = I; // ADDED // Here I want R to be the real part of the already created matrix img_mat (also I as imaginary part)

    }

    plhs[0]=img_mat;

    mexPrintf("  %  ",plhs[0]);

}
```

Now after summing all elements of mat_1 and mat_2 into (R and I) respectively, I'm trying to set (R) as real part of the already created matrix img_mat and also (I) as imaginary part but nothing seems to be working.
Can somebody please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Nothing seems to working" - what is not working? Your question is a little unclear - but after a short look: if you mean printing "plhs" is not working - you are not writing anything to img_mat nor to "plhs[0]". You need to copy from mat_x to img_mat or use the already created matrices directly (use mat_x(a, b) = 42). http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm

Comment: Hello Denis,
You are right .. I didn't make myself clear enough. After computing (R and I) I tried the following solution (which I didn't include in the code) :
.
.
.
R = R + mat_1[o];
I = I + mat_2[o]; 
double *rptr, *iptr;
R_ptr = (double *) mxMalloc(1*1 * sizeof(double));
I_ptr = (double *) mxMalloc(1*1 * sizeof(double));
rptr[o] = R; 
iptr[o] = I; 
}//end of for loop here
plhs[0]=img_mat;
mexPrintf("  %  ",plhs[0]);
} //end of mex file here
Now what I get is 5 complex elements of the matrix img_mat, but what I need is the sum of those elements into one complex term

Comment: (of real and imaginary part) any help please?
P.S I edited my question and added the modification above to my code for a clearer view.